# sc_trans metadataPattern

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

metadataPattern

> The pattern used to extract metadata from a file name if metadata does not exist
>   or useMetadata == 0.
>
> default is */%N.* for unix and *\%N.* for windows
>
> %N = song name
>     %G = genre
>     %A = album
>     %R = artist
>     %Y = four digit year
>     %# = sequence of digits
>     %% = % character
>     [] = brackets optional elements (no nesting)
>     *  = string
>     other characters match exactly
>
> pattern matching is done from right to left.
>
> Examples:
>
> pattern = */%R/%Y%A/Audio/[%#_]%N.*
>     path = /home/nradisch/songs/Mask and Wig/1969 Irreverance Of Things Past/Audio/03_The Royal Blues.mp3
>     result:
>      ALBUM  Irreverance Of Things Past
>      ARTIST  Mask and Wig
>      SONG  The Royal Blues
>      YEAR  1969

My Question is how can I make it display `/var/radio/%folderNAME%/*.*`?  It has to ignore all the other folders that could be inside `%folderNAME%`.

If you know `sc_trans` and have other solutions to make it not display the song title and display a custom name that would be good too.

Comment: You may want to ask this on superuser.com instead.  They have a [`shoutcast` tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shoutcast) there.